Windows 11 Closed Caption universal alternative
So I want to have Closed Caption (subtitles) for times when I talk to people on Discord, Zoom calls and whatnot. I know some software supports it but not all. It would be great if I could have something that's just universal and it'd work.
I tried using OBS captions plugin but it's very rough. Gets maybe 5% right.
It's okay if I have to buy a subscription for it too as long as it's affordable for personal use and it works OK.
I am also aware that Windows 11 has Closed Captions but I'm not sure if it's good enough. I remember trying it out once and it was "meh".

Did my answer help?

The OBS plugin you've linked has been dead for a while. This is a new actively developed one: LocalVocal.
It depends on whisper.cpp - a popular open source model/library. How accurate it'll be depends on the hardware that you have - with good CPU or GPU you could go for at least small or medium model. And of course on audio quality of your device and clarity of your voice and language.
It can output the text to any Text source or to various file formats.
Then you can utilize OBS virtual cam to display the caption in many apps.

In case if you did not know, Chrome browser  has its own closed caption ? I don't have Windows 11 with me so I don't know what's like  but when I am on Windows 10 and have Chrome and whenever someone speak, the dialog box will show up automatically . Also, MS Teams has their own closed captioned and sign language in box .

What? How is that related to my answer? Post your own answer if you have a different suggestion, although the author was talking about different apps, so not sure that'd be an accurate answer.
